# how to use a static instance of HttpClient with multiple consumers

Tags: c#, .net, httpclient, azure-functions

**How do we reuse a static instance of HttpClient?**

I have a static `HttpClient` that I would like to reuse concurrently:

```
    private static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
```

I'm creating my request like so:

```
            var attachTopic = GetEnvironmentVariable("Attach:EventTopicUri");
            var attachTopicKey = GetEnvironmentVariable("Attach:EventTopicKey");
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(attachTopic);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("aeg-sas-key", attachTopicKey);
```

And then posting the request:

`await client.PostAsJsonAsync("", new[] { /*some awesome object*/ });`

However, I'm getting the following issue:

[image: etc]

**How do we make concurrent requests with the same header information on a static HttpClient?**

Comment: You can't set properties like `BaseAddress` or `client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();` across multiple concurrent requests like that. I'd suggest setting the `DefaultRequestHeaders` once (at startup) and not setting `BaseAddress` at all. Alternatively, have separate `HttpClient` objects in a Dictionary which is keyed by `string`. Then put multiple shared clients in there, each with a different `BaseAddress`.

Comment: If you use .NET Core, [HttpClientFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests) will return static HttpClients for each `BaseAddress`, and updates the connection if DNS resolution changes.

Comment: Further to @mjwills comment, your `BaseAddress` should be the domain of which you're sending request too, which shouldn't change across requests, your request URL used in `GetAsync` will change as that's the path/resource you're requesting from the domain. If the domains are different then they're different `HttpClient` instances which are reused per domain, as Dour High Arch has pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you introduce dependency injection to your project. You can see the oficial docs [HERE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection).

The first example in the docs adds `HttpClient` to the service provider:

```cs
public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
{
    builder.Services.AddHttpClient();
    builder.Services.AddSingleton((s) => {
        return new CosmosClient(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("COSMOSDB_CONNECTIONSTRING"));
    });
    builder.Services.AddSingleton<ILoggerProvider, MyLoggerProvider>();
}
```

To use your HttpClient, you'll have to inject it to your functions class constructor:

```cs
public class MyFunc
{
    private readonly HttpClient _client;

    public MyFunc(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
    {
        _client = httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
    }

    [FunctionName("DoSomething")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", Route = "do-something")] HttpRequest req,
        ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
        var res = await _client.GetAsync("my-cool-url.com);

        return new OkResult(res);
   }
}
```

What I especially like about this approach, is that you can create different keyed clients when you register it to the DI:

```cs
private void ConfigureService(IWebJobBuilder builder)
{
    // Some logic
    builder.Services.AddHttpClient("aaa", client =>
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("base-address.com");
    });
}
```

And then use it like this:

```cs
public MyFunc(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
{
    _client = httpClientFactory.CreateClient("aaa");
}
```

Let me know if something isn't working for you. :)

Comment: This is the proper way to do this.

Comment: How would you set headers in this case? DefaultRequestHeader.Add should only be used on instantiation of the client.

Comment: That's a completely different answer. There are very few cases in which I'd recommend to set default request headers. The proper way, IMHO, is to use Http Handlers to add headers per request. But, if you insist on initializing the default header, you can add them in the configuration part. Check the method ConfigureService in my answer. Just as I set there a BaseAddress, you can set there any other value you want and it would happen only once, when initializing the instance.